# Using Android Studio Emulator Back Button

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm new to android and I'm trying to develop an app. My question is when I open the emulator in the android studio, there is return button at the bottom. Therefore, does this mean that I do not have to implement the return button when I want to navigate from one view back to the previous view? Can I just use the default return button of the android app?

Comment: Yes you can. When you pressed the back button, it goes directly `onBackPressed()` method(same as real devices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I open the emulator in the android studio, there is return button at the bottom.

It's not just emulator but all Android devices have bottom control buttons. One of which is always Home, another is always Back and the third one depends on OS and Manufacturer. The alignment also depends on OS, Manufacturer or Launcher App.

> does this mean that I do not have to implement the return button when I want to navigate from one view back to the previous view?

If you are working with activities only then back button closes current activity, hence bringing you to previously opened activity. However, there are cases when you'd need to explicitly handle back button. [See developer reference here](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html).

Also I'd recommend reading about [Up and Back Navigation](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html).